# Enabling ResourceMonitorService addon for Service Fabric local cluster fails

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I' m attempting to enable the Resource Monitor Service addon for a Service Fabric cluster on my local machine as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-autoscaling#auto-scaling-based-on-resources

I added the value to the json, but when I attempt to reset my cluster, it fails with the following error:

```
JSON config is invalid. Check syntax/model.:Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "ResourceMonitorService" to type 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.ClusterManagementCommon.AddonFeature'. Path 'properties.addOnFeatures[1]', line 324, position 70. ---> System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'ResourceMonitorService' was not found.
   at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)
   at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.EnumUtils.ParseEnumName(String enumText, Boolean isNullable, Type t)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.Model.StandAloneInstallerJsonModelBase.DeserializeJsonConfig(Type type, String json)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.DeploymentManager.Model.StandAloneInstallerJsonModelBase.GetJsonConfigFromString(String jsonString)
```

I'm kind of stuck at this point. I can't find any information about the enum or what valid values are for the addons.

here's the json section snippet:

```
"addOnFeatures": [
      "DnsService",
      "ResourceMonitorService"
    ]
```

Comment: What version of Service Fabric are you on? I think this wasn't introduced until 6.3

Comment: It was introduced in 6.2 - I was just made aware. Are you on 6.2?

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I was on 6.0 on my local and upgrading to 6.3 fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as Mikkel commented, the feature was added in a later version than the one I had installed. To fix, I just upgraded to latest version of service fabric. It didn't work right away, I had to reboot my local machine before it would work. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: How did you upgrade service fabric?

Comment: @PaulBrittain Just downloaded the latest service fabric tools / SDK from the website